# What method do I need to define to implement inspect function in nodejs/v8

Tags: node.js, v8

I have a C++ class integrated into NodeJS, I would like to change its default object printing

example:

```
var X = new mypkg.Thing() ;
console.log( X ) ;             // prints the object in std way
console.log( X.toString() ) ;  // prints Diddle aye day
console.log( '' + X ) ;        // prints Diddle aye day
```

I have defined ToString in the external code, that works. But I want the default printing to be the same.

```
 void WrappedThing::ToString( const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args ) {
     Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
     args.GetReturnValue().Set( String::NewFromUtf8( isolate, "Diddle aye day") );
 }
```

Is there an 'Inspect' method to override?

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a section on this in the node.js [`util` documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_custom_inspection_functions_on_objects). Basically you can either expose an `inspect()` method on the object/class *or* set the function via the special `util.inspect.custom` symbol on the object.

Here is one example using the special symbol:

```
const util = require('util');

const obj = { foo: 'this will not show up in the inspect() output' };
obj[util.inspect.custom] = function(depth, options) {
  return { bar: 'baz' };
};

// Prints: "{ bar: 'baz' }"
console.log(util.inspect(obj));
```

Comment: That did it: a c++ method called Inspect - same prototype as ToString()

Comment: From my testing it seems as though the [util.inspect.custom] symbol is the only one that still works as of right now.